# Boost.Range algorithm for getting the nth element of a range

Tags: c++, boost, range

Is there a way to get the n'th element of a range using Boost.Range? (I am **not** talking about the `nth_element` algorithm which returns the element that would be in n'th position if the range were sorted. I simply want the n'th element according to the current order of elements in the range).

I would expect this function to work on both forward and random-access ranges (being linear-time in the case of forward ranges and constant time in the case of random-access ranges), and to throw an exception (`std::out_of_range` perhaps) if the range has fewer than `n` elements.

I know this can by `std::advance`-ing the `begin()` iterator of the range by `n`, but I'm looking for a range-based solution which doesn't descend to the level of iterators.

**EDIT**: Actually, this can't be done with `std::advance` because `std::advance` doesn't check if you're going past the end of the range.

Comment: @yi_H: `std::advance` doesn't check if you're going past the end of the range (because it doesn't know about the end iterator). I would like an exception to be thrown if that happens.

Comment: "but I'm looking for a range-based solution which doesn't descend to the level of iterators" - in the end, it of course will go down to the iterators.

Comment: @Xeo: Of course, much as the STL descends to the level of pointers in the end. But we don't want to program at the level of pointers when we can avoid it, right?

Comment: Well, once you wrote that function, you're done. You *need* to write the code that interacts with the layers.

Comment: @Xeo: I know. I was merely wondering whether there is something in Boost.Range that already does it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything like that built in, but it seems pretty easy to implement:

```c
namespace details {

template<typename RangeT, typename IterCatT>
typename boost::range_reference<RangeT>::type nth_impl(
    RangeT& range,
    typename boost::range_difference<RangeT>::type n,
    IterCatT const)
{
    typedef typename boost::range_iterator<RangeT>::type iter_t;

    iter_t first = boost::begin(range), last = boost::end(range);
    while (n--)
        if (++first == last)
            throw std::range_error("n");
    return *first;
}

template<typename RangeT>
typename boost::range_reference<RangeT>::type nth_impl(
    RangeT& range,
    typename boost::range_difference<RangeT>::type const n,
    std::random_access_iterator_tag const)
{
    if (boost::size(range) <= n)
        throw std::range_error("n");

    return *(boost::begin(range) + n);
}

}

template<typename RangeT>
typename boost::range_reference<RangeT>::type nth(
    RangeT& range,
    typename boost::range_difference<RangeT>::type const n)
{
    return details::nth_impl(
        range,
        n,
        typename boost::range_category<RangeT>::type()
    );
}
```

Comment: This will needlessly traverse a forward range twice.

Comment: @HighCommander4 : A sane specialization of `boost::size` for e.g. a container that knows its own size but offers non-random-access iterators will use that container's size member function. I.e., in any reasonable circumstance, invoking `boost::size` will involve no traversal whatsoever.

Comment: Yes, but even for a forward range that doesn't know its size (e.g. `std::forward_list`, or any range passed through the `filtered` adaptor), it's not necessary to traverse twice - you can advance the iterator and check that it hasn't reached the end at the same time.

Comment: @HighCommander: Well, if you want to pay the price for checking on every iteration.

Comment: @HighCommander4 : Answer edited, but this really seems like something you could have done yourself. ;-]

Comment: @Xeo: What do you think `boost::size()` would have done in such a case if not check on every iteration?

Comment: @ildjarn: Yes, I could have. I just didn't want to accept an answer with unnecessary performance problems ;-] (There are still optimizations to be made, such as specializing it for random-access ranges, but I think it gets the idea across).

Comment: @HighCommander4 : Fair enough, answer edited to include specialization for random-access ranges. :-]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the similar issue. I solved it using [boost::adaptor::strided](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/strided.html).